# Ionic 3 How to select specific ion-chip on click event?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have bunch of ion-chips generated by ngFor loop. I have added select all ion-chips functionality using `tagDefaultColor` variable. Right now when I want to select single ion-chip it selects all of them.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to use toggle all button to select every `ion-chip` or select them one by one with click event. Once `ion-chip` is selected it changes its color to primary. Thank you in advance.

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.information = navParams.data.data;
    this.children = [{ id: 1, name: 'Ginny Weasley' }, { id: 2, name: 'Harry Potter' }, { id: 3, name: 'Ronald Weasley' }, { id: 4, name: 'Luna Lovegood' }];
    this.selectButtonText = 'SELECT ALL';
    //this.tagSelectedColor = "primary";
    this.tagDefaultColor = "secondary";
    this.quantity = 0.0;
    this.shareWithFamily = true;
  }
```

```js
selectAll() {
    if (this.selectButtonText === 'SELECT ALL') {
      this.selectButtonText = 'UNSELECT ALL'
      this.tagDefaultColor = "primary";
    } else {
      this.selectButtonText = 'SELECT ALL'
      this.tagDefaultColor = "secondary"
    }
  }
```

```js
changeTagColor(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    if (this.tagDefaultColor === "secondary") {
      this.tagDefaultColor = "primary"
    } else {
      this.tagDefaultColor = "secondary"
      event.target.setAttribute('color', 'secondary')
    }
  }
```

HTML part

```html
<ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col style="display: flex;align-items: center; justify-content: center">
          <strong>Tag Students</strong>
          <button ion-button full color="primary" class="select-all-btn" (click)="selectAll()">{{selectButtonText}}
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>

    <div class="students-tags">
      <ion-chip [id]="child.id" [color]="tagDefaultColor" (click)="changeTagColor($event)" *ngFor="let child of children">
        <ion-label>{{child. name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your chips bind to  same property so if you change that they will all change. Instead you should use array to assign them individually like below :

```
<ion-chip [id]="child.id" [color]="tagDefaultColor[i]" (click)="changeTagColor(i)" *ngFor="let child of children;let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{child. name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
```

```
changeTagColor(i:number) {
    console.log(event.target);
    if (this.tagDefaultColor[i] === "secondary") {
      this.tagDefaultColor[i] = "primary"
    } else {
      this.tagDefaultColor[i] = "secondary"
      // event.target.setAttribute('color', 'secondary') this is redundant
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**
Since ionic doesn't export a component sadly you cant use template ref to change color directly with component.

And as you asked in comments there is an easy way to populate colors array like below :

```
  tagDefaultColor = Array(this.children.length).fill("secondary");
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wvnw3t) is the Stackblitz sample.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However the chip.color returns undefined for me. In case of using array I would have to assign tagDefault to `['secondary', 'secondary', 'secondary', 'secondary']` to be able to change it once it clicked?

Comment: Thanks It is working great. Now I need to implement function for select/deselct all.

Comment: @Eldar do you know how to implement the same functionality with ionic/vue? Using vue3

Comment: @Verthon did you settle for manually assigning tagDefault? If not, what solution did you come up with?

Comment: @carlhandy you can have a similar solution with vue3. The syntax may differ whether you use composition API or not. Basically explaining you need to have an array filled with default color names. Bind your chip colors to that array's corresponding item. On click change the color in the position.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. The Stackblitz is not working for me. I guess it's because it's missing the CSS.

Comment: @Yster I've fixed it. It's not the CSS it's the parameters of the method, some have I had extra parameter which is undefined. Setting the `color` property will apply the appropriate styles.